# Activity feed for all the members of the site

Tags: activity-feed

Is it possible to get all the activity feed of all members in a site? I tried `http://servername/my/_layouts/activityfeed.aspx?consolidated=true` but this returns all the activity feeds for your colleagues only. Is there a way to get all the feeds from all the members in the site even if you are not colleagues? In this way you can monitor all the activities of the site members. Or is it possible to pass the group name to `http://servername/my/_layouts/activityfeed.aspx?publisher=groupname` or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colleague list is core to the Activity Feed functionality so there would be no easy way to accomplish what you are looking to do.  The only way I can think of to trick the system would be to create an account and make all of the site members colleagues and then find a way to grab the colleague list for that user account.

Getting the feed for any of the other site members would include items from their other colleagues as well.